# Grow spinning ArcSegment into full circle

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard

I've built a little spinner icon in XAML using an `ArcSegment` that is moved along a circular `Path`. After some time I'd like my spinner to grow in size to create a full circle.

This is what my animation looks like while it's moving (choppiness is due to the desktop capture): [image]

I'll explain my thought process. We can take a look at the image at a random point at the rotation and talk about how we'd grow it into a full circle:

- Radius: 10
- Canvas: 22x22
- Arc StartPoint: 18.071, 3.929
- Arc EndPoint: 22,11

[image: Sample Circle]

I believe I just need to use a storyboard with a `PointAnimationUsingPath` that goes from **(22,11)** to **(18.071, 3.929)** in a clockwise direction.

My question is: How can I create a `PointAnimationUsingPath` that is created based on the current values of my `ArcSegment`?

I've included the XAML. If anything needs clarification, let me know.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestingIcons.icons.Processing"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestingIcons.icons"
             xmlns:sysWin="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=WindowsBase"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Background="White"
             d:DesignHeight="22" d:DesignWidth="22">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <sysWin:Point x:Key="topCenterPoint">11 1</sysWin:Point>
        <sysWin:Point x:Key="topRightPoint">18.071 3.929</sysWin:Point>
        <sysWin:Point x:Key="bottomCenterPoint">11 21</sysWin:Point>
        <sysWin:Point x:Key="bottomLeftPoint">3.929 18.071</sysWin:Point>
        <sysWin:Size x:Key="circleSize">10 10</sysWin:Size>

        <Storyboard x:Key="SpinningAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation 
                Storyboard.TargetName="outerPath"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>

            <!--Reset the arc to a single point-->
            <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                Storyboard.TargetName="startArc"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="StartPoint"
                >
                <!--Always grow the arc from its starting position-->
                <DiscretePointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{StaticResource topCenterPoint}"/>
            </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <!-- Grow the arc from a point -->
            <PointAnimationUsingPath
                Storyboard.TargetName="endArc"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point"
                Duration="0:0:0.2"
                AccelerationRatio="0.5">
                <PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="{StaticResource topCenterPoint}" IsClosed="False">
                            <ArcSegment
                                Point="{StaticResource topRightPoint}"
                                Size="{StaticResource circleSize}" 
                                IsLargeArc="False"
                                SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            </PointAnimationUsingPath>

            <!--Animate the start of the arc in a circle-->
            <PointAnimationUsingPath 
                Storyboard.TargetName="startArc"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="StartPoint"
                Duration="0:0:0.8"
                BeginTime="0:0:0.2"
                AccelerationRatio="0.4"
                >
                <PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="{StaticResource topCenterPoint}">
                            <ArcSegment Size="{StaticResource circleSize}" Point="{StaticResource bottomCenterPoint}"
                                            SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                            <ArcSegment Size="{StaticResource circleSize}" Point="{StaticResource topCenterPoint}"
                                            SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            </PointAnimationUsingPath>

            <!-- Animate the end of the arc in a circle-->
            <PointAnimationUsingPath 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="endArc"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point"
                    Duration="0:0:0.8"
                    BeginTime="0:0:0.2"
                    AccelerationRatio="0.4"
                    >
                <PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="{StaticResource topRightPoint}">
                            <ArcSegment Size="{StaticResource circleSize}" Point="{StaticResource bottomLeftPoint}"
                                                SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                            <ArcSegment Size="{StaticResource circleSize}" Point="{StaticResource topRightPoint}"
                                                SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            </PointAnimationUsingPath>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SpinningAnimation}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>

    <Canvas>
        <Path x:Name="outerPath" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="{StaticResource topCenterPoint}">
                        <ArcSegment Size="{StaticResource circleSize}" Point="{StaticResource bottomCenterPoint}" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
                        <ArcSegment Size="{StaticResource circleSize}" Point="{StaticResource topCenterPoint}" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>

        <Path x:Name="eighthOfCircle" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure x:Name="startArc" StartPoint="{StaticResource topCenterPoint}" IsClosed="False">
                        <ArcSegment x:Name="endArc"
                                Point="{StaticResource topRightPoint}"
                                Size="{StaticResource circleSize}" 
                                IsLargeArc="False"
                                SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Note that this would get difficult as soon as the arc segment covers more than 180°. You would then also have to switch the IsLargeArc property.

Comment: Yup, but I think can use a `BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames` to switch `IsLargeArc` halfway through the duration of the storyboard.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Blend for Visual Studio installed, open your project in there and you will see that there are a lot more options for shapes. For example:

```
    <ed:Arc ArcThickness="20"
        ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel"
        EndAngle="270"
        Fill="#FFF4F4F5"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Height="100"
        Stretch="None"
        Stroke="Black"
        StartAngle="0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="100"/>
```

The namespace introduced by blend is:

```
xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"
```

And it adds a reference to:

```
Microsoft.Expression.Drawing
```

With that shape you can animate the start and end angles to make the arc grow.
Here's an example:

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate
            TargetType = "{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Storyboard
                    x:Key = "TheAnimation">
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName = "TheArc"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty = "EndAngle"
                        From = "0"
                        To = "360"
                        RepeatBehavior = "Forever"
                        Duration = "0:0:1"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName = "TheRotationTransform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Angle"
                        From = "0"
                        To = "360"
                        RepeatBehavior = "Forever"
                        Duration = "0:0:1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger
                    Property = "Visibility"
                    Value = "Visible">
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <StopStoryboard
                            BeginStoryboardName = "TheAnimation_BeginStoryboard"/>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard
                            x:Name = "TheAnimation_BeginStoryboard"
                            Storyboard = "{StaticResource TheAnimation}"/>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Border
                Height = "100"
                Width = "100"
                RenderTransformOrigin = "0.5,0.5">
                <ed:Arc
                    x:Name = "TheArc"
                    ArcThickness = "10"
                    ArcThicknessUnit = "Pixel"
                    Fill = "Blue"
                    EndAngle = "90"
                    Height = "100"
                    HorizontalAlignment = "Right"
                    StartAngle = "0"
                    Stretch = "None"
                    VerticalAlignment = "Top"
                    Width = "100"/>
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform
                            x:Name = "TheRotationTransform"
                            Angle = "0"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Border.RenderTransform>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: I'm using something similar. (ArgSegment) With both of them, I need to get access to the current position of the arc that's being rotated in a circle. That's the part I'm struggling with.

Comment: Animate the rotation using the rotation transform and them just update the end angle from 0 to 360 and it should work, i'll post an example.

Comment: The issue isn't rotating it in a circle. The issue is growing it into a full circle from its current position. (It might be rotated at any point)

Comment: I updated my answer, the example has an arc rotating and growing, the key thing here is that I set Stretch to None on the Arc.